# Combination function in numpy that be applied as vectorized method on a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe with around 45 million rows and I need to apply a method to calculate combinations of two columns. So the the function needs to be applied on all rows. For loop works with comb function from math module however takes lot of time, .apply also seems to be not viable option. I tried 3 other options

**Option 1**
comb function from math module as vectorized operation

```
df1['comb'] = comb(df1['c1'],df1['c2'])
```

This throws the error TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

**Option2**

```
df1['comb'] = np.vectorize(comb_fun)(df1['c1'],df1['c2'])
```

This works however still takes time

**Option 3**

```
import scipy.special as ss
df1['comb'] = ss.comb(df1['c1'],df1['c2'])
```

This works, gives fast results however gives floating point results which affects my further calculations.  When I use `exact=True` to avoid floating point precision, it gives the following error

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

If anyone of you know other function/ way that can be applied as vectorized operation on data frame to calculate combinations please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: what is the function that you want to apply to two values?

Comment: @Haleemur Ali function is to calculate combination of two columns in the data frame like math.comb(n, k)

Comment: thanks, i missed that detail. `ss.special.comb` is probably your best bet in terms of ease of use & speed. can you update your questions to share some sample rows of your `df` & also the output of `df.dtypes`.